# Ionic/Cordova iOS - invoke function on app open

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Is it possible to invoke a function after applications is re-opened (closed with home button, not closed as a process)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using by injecting the $ionicPlatform service into either a run block (for the entire app) or into a single controller.

Here is an example of it in a run block:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
        // Do sweet stuff!
    });
}
```

And here it is in a controller:

```
.controller(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
        // Do sweet stuff!
    });
}
```

Note that this is really just a wrapper for [Cordova's resume lifecycle event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume). You can see more information about the $ionicPlatform service and the 'on' method in the Ionic framework docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/).